# Neutralize All Threats - Am I required to trash the second card accessed if I was not able to trash the first one?

Tags: android-netrunner

I've got the [Neutralize All Threats](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/09043) and one credit. I make a run, say on a remote server, and access [Space Camp](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/07010). Since it costs 3 credits to trash, I can't afford the cost to trash it. Then I make a run, say on another remote server and access the [Melange Mining Corp](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01108). Does [Neutralize All Threats](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/09043) force me to trash it?

[image: Neutralize All Threats from "Data and Destiny"]
[image: Space Camp from "Order and Chaos"]
[image: Melange Mining Corp. from Core Set]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it doesn't force you. Neutralize All Threats triggers *"the first time each turn you access a card with trash cost..."* and whatever you did with that card is irrelevant for next accesses same turn.